# Output of converting binary to Decimal not expected?

Tags: java, string

> Given a binary number as input convert it into base 10 (decimal system). Note that to convert a number 100111 from binary to decimal, the value is 1*2^5 + 0*2^4 + 0*2^3 + 1*2^2 + 1*2^1+ 1*2^0. Also note that 5 here is the length of the binary number.

**MyApproach**

To convert to decimal,I first converted the code from String to decimal.Then I solved the number till it is greater than 0 and solved the expression.

For example for number 10=0*2^0+1*2^1 and solved the expression in the code.

> I am getting a wrong Ans on the last test case.
>   Can anyone guide me what is wrong in my code.?

Below is my code:

```
public int convert(String binary)
{
int p=0;
int decimal=0;

int number=Integer.parseInt(binary);
while(number>0)
{
  int temp = number%10;
     decimal += temp*Math.pow(2, p);
     number = number/10;
     p++;
  //write your code here

 }
 return decimal;
} 
}

Parameters     ActualOutput      ExpectedOutput

'10011010010'    null             1234
```

Comment: Could you not just use the binary string as-is and use `charAt`?

Comment: Well you haven't shown how you're coming up with "ActualOutput". Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Personally, I would treat string as a character array and then loop through that, using the (length - position) as the power of 2.

Comment: Try reversing string before converting to `int` and a lot better approach would be to extracting chars from string and perform computation in loop.

Comment: @NirLevy I am getting a wrong Ans on the last test case.Can anyone guide me why?

Comment: In Java by default, the int data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer, which has a minimum value of -2^31 and a maximum value of (2^31)-1. You are exceeding this range when converting the string to int.

Comment: @tato.rodrigo And how to control that

Comment: You can parse it to `long` or implement something like @DBug said (which I would do if I were in your place)

Comment: @DBug , yes only char, and without pow: see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Max value of integer is (2^31-1) and the value that you are parsing to int from string in greater than that. Hence try to use Long in place of int  ..
below code is working fine.. please check it below..

```
public static int convert(String binary)
    {
    int p=0;
    int decimal=0;

    long number=Long.parseLong(binary);
    while(number>0)
    {
      long temp = number%10;
         decimal += temp*Math.pow(2, p);
         number = number/10;
         p++;
      //write your code here

     }
     return decimal;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simpler, without pow :

```
int s=binary.length();

for (int pos=0;pos<s;pos++)
{
char c=binary.charAt(pos);
if (c=='1') decimal+=1;
if (pos<s-1) decimal*=2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input is above the limit of `int` in Java, which is `2,147,483,647`. 
Even if if you change it to `long`, you won't be able to convert values above `1000000000000000000` (which is equal to `262144` in decimal). Best solution is to calculate by taking character by character without converting the whole string.

So, try the following code,

```
public static long convert(String binary) {
    long pow = 1, decimal = 0;
    for (int i = (binary.length() - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
        if (binary.charAt(i) == '1') {
            decimal += pow;
        }
        pow *= 2;
    }
    return decimal;
}
```

Comment: MyQuestion: In the Code I wrote what changes are to be made

Answer (score 0):

Why convert it to decimal first? This is quite easy:

```
   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      String str = "10011010010";
      int len = str.length();
      long mult = 1;
      long val = 0;
      for (int i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
         if ( str.charAt( i ) == '1' ) {
            val += mult;
         }
         mult *= 2;
      }
      System.out.println( val );
   }
```